# Retrieve selected strings from a list of words using Java

Tags: java, string, user-interface

I would like to know are there any way to retrieve selected words from a string. Example I would like to retrieve the bold words from my textfile.

Below is the list of words which i would like to retrieve:

Item [**00001**: **Chemical Engineering** by **R C Lodeen**: 
on loan to borrower 001: Mr X (41, NX4 4XZ)] borrowed by [**001**: **Mr X** (41, NX4 4XZ)]; **timestamp 1418119171904**

I have tried searching on google but the solution which they provide didnt help me. Can anyone guide me on how to solve this problem.

Comment: What kind of [tag:markup] does the text file use?

Comment: What kind of file you are using please (doc, pdf...) ?

Comment: Isn't SGML an XML-based language? Your example data surely isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a set of criteria in order to determine which words you want to retrieve, such as "Retrieve all characters that follow a '[' symbol until a ':' is found". After you have defined such a set, use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to select your words.

Comment: how to define the set? Actually i am new to regular expressions

Comment: You'll need to define the sets as regular expressions, so I guess you need to learn about them, maybe by using the link in my answer, or by doing [this tutorial](http://regexone.com/).